# How i save and show existing progress status using flask socketio if browser is closed(session)

Tags: flask, session-cookies, session-state, flask-socketio, flask-session

Requirement :-

working on a project with flask.

flask socketIo ...and i have almost completed the project.
Now i want to implement something which is very common on web development.

Right now i can show the status of background tasks in the UI, and events are getting send to specfic (request.sid ). Now if the user accidentally close his browser and and returns to the same page, for obvious reason he won't see anything ( which was happening in the existing session) but the initial page 
I want to a way if the user again comes to the page, it should be redirected to the current status page.

Am trying to achieve something exactly like any cloud based solutions For example if i create an Ec2 instance from console and close it. Upon reopening it will still show the existing operations with current status ( running,pending ) etc..
How can achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

> if the user accidentally close his browser and and returns to the same page, for obvious reason he won't see anything

This isn't really obvious. If your user is logged in to your application then you know them, and presumably you also know what background task each user has pending. When the user returns to the page and logs in again, you should be able to find the state of any background tasks associated with the user.

The only situation in which you would not be able to do this is if you don't require your users to authenticate, in which case when the user comes to your page the second time you have no way to know it is the same user that closed the page before. The fix for this problem is to use authentication, so that your users are always known to the server.

Comment: Yes you are correct. Let me correct my question. The thing is when the same user reopens the same page again, it's not showing any previous states. I am thinking to store the status in server side sessions. Now the issue am having is a, unable to use flask session inside threads, as variables inside threads are threads local. Do you have any existing solution or idea to achieve this.

Comment: def long_task(app, i):

    # global session
    print "started executing for {}".format(i)

    time.sleep(5)
    print "working"
    session['step1'][i]["status"] = 'Completed' ---> This doesn't work
    send_msg('step1', {"nodename":i,"status":"completed"})

Comment: Store the state in your database, so that you can recall it when the user logs back in.

Comment: Thanks miguel....i was thinking to skip the database part ( our team had an approach to store the results in database and then ajax long polling to show them in UI).. i implemented socketio...so was thinking if we can use session to store existing status ..

Comment: The session will go away when the browser is closed. You can store the state in a cookie, or else configure the user session with an expiration time, so that it stays when the browser is closed.